# jQuery autocomplete mysql zend no response from action/controller?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, jquery-autocomplete

Were using jquery autocomplete in zend and setup our action like this

```
public function ajaxautocompleteAction()
{
    $postData = $this->_request->getParams();
    $term = $postData['term'];
    $categoryObj = new Categories();
    $result = $categoryObj->searchCategory($term);
    $this->view->result = $result;
}
```

The javascript in the view file is this

```
    $(function() {
        var url = "http://www.domain.com/account/ajaxautocomplete?format=json";
        $( "#autotest" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response){
                var iterm = request.term;
                var url = "http://www.domain.com/account/ajaxautocomplete?format=json";
                $.post( url, {term: iterm},
                function( data ) {
            response(data); });
            }
    });
});
```

In chrome console i get this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com/account/ajaxautocomplete?format=json. Origin http://domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any ideas why were not getting results from the ajax request?

Comment: Editing our url's to non wwww which is how their set in zend started to work, I see in chrome console "XHR finished loading:...." but no select list

Comment: chrome console shows XHR finished loading: "http://domain.com/account/ajaxautocomplete?format=json" it should have ?term=asdf being the letters I started to type but it's not picking that up, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've used jQueryUI's autocomplete and ZF before...

1. Create your action

   ```
   public function ajaxautocompleteAction()
   {
       $term = $this->getRequest()->getParam('term');
       $categoryObj = new Categories();
       $result = $categoryObj->searchCategory($term);
       $this->view->result = $result;
   }
   ```
2. Add an AjaxContext to your action, disabling automatic JSON serialisation. I'm skipping the auto serialisation as it's not common for your models to represent the usual "label" / "value" pairs jQueryUI's automcomplete looks for

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('ajaxautocomplete', 'json')
                                  ->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)
                                  ->initContext('json');
   }
   ```
3. Create your JSON view (`views/scripts/account/ajaxautocomplete.json.phtml`)

   ```
   <?php
   $data = array();
   foreach ($this->results as $category) {
       // format each result for jQueryUI autocomplete
       $data[] = array(
           'label' => $category->getName(),
           'value' => $category->getName()
       );            
   }
   echo Zend_Json::encode($data);
   ```
4. Add the URL for your autocomplete action as a JavaScript variable to the view that needs to use it (assuming you use the HeadScript helper in your layout)

   ```
   $this->headScript()->prependScript(sprintf('var searchUrl = "%s";',
       $this->url(array(
           'action'     => 'ajaxautocomplete',
           'controller' => 'account'
       ), null, true)));
   ```
5. Setup your JavaScript like this

   ```
   $("#autotest").autocomplete({
       source: searchUrl,
       minLength: 2
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, are you able to get the row ID from your database and have the input set with that name/ID? And are you validating it with any code so users dont enter some value that's not coming from your db table?

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend using a standard Zend Form with select element and enhance it with the [Chosen plugin]( http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Answer (score -1):

looks like domain.com does not allow cross-domain calls.

Try `chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

Comment: I don't think this is the answer there's no way all our website visitors are going to be doing this in chrome. And I don't see what file:// has to do with this? We're getting a list of categories from our mysql table, trying to turn it into an autocomplete through a zend action.

Comment: please forget about 'file://', I edited answer earlier :)
Of course you visitors will not setup chrome.
It is your web server that does not allow this type of requests. Try adding in response header something like `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com")`